# Flutter bloc navigation with and without Equatable

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-navigation

When [bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) states extended from [Equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable), I'm able to navigate only ones to another screen. Otherwise, when states are not extended from Equatable, I'm able to navigate to another screen as much as I want to.

I know that states and events should be extended from Equatable by Best Practises in order to be able to run bloc tests. Also it is possible to override Back button behaviour on second screen with Second bloc and do `Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {return const FirstPage();}))`, but it seems like a wrong move.

Question: Is it possible to navigate to other screen more then one time using Equatable without overriding back button functionality on second screen?

Code:

bloc

```dart
// main_bloc.dart
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

// bloc
class MainBloc extends Bloc<MainEvent, MainState> {
  MainBloc() : super(MainInitial()) {
    on<OpenSecondPageEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(OpeningSecondPageState());
    });
  }
}

// States
abstract class MainState extends Equatable {
  const MainState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class MainInitial extends MainState {}

class OpeningSecondPageState extends MainState {}

// Events
abstract class MainEvent extends Equatable {
  const MainEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class OpenSecondPageEvent extends MainEvent {}
```

UI

```dart
// main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: BlocProvider(

        create: (context) => MainBloc(),
        child: BlocConsumer<MainBloc, MainState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is OpeningSecondPageState) {
               Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                return const SecondPage(); // <- Navigating to second screen
              }));
            }
          },
          builder: (context, state) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text('Page A'),
              ),
              body: Center(
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Open Page B'),
                  onPressed: () =>
                      context.read<MainBloc>().add(OpenSecondPageEvent()),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Page B'),
      ),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

With Equatable
[image]

Without Equatable
[image]

Comment: Just curious, why set up `Bloc` just for this basic navigation? You have no other business logic in your bloc, so why not just do the navigation directly in the `onPressed` and be done with it? That would give you the behavior you're looking for. It seems to be a lot of extra code with no benefit. That being said, it's only working once because `Equatable` doesn't consider it a new state after one push. First push is `MainInitial ` to `OpeningSecondPageState` so that works. 2nd push is already `OpeningSecondPageState` so `BlocBuilder` wont react to what it considers the same state.

Comment: @Loren.A answering your question, what you can see is just an example made of from more complicated app. I removed everything what is not related to the question. As for the states considered the same on 2nd push I'm aware from my other experience, but thanks anyway for highlighting this. I want to find out is there any way to make `BlocBuilder` to react to 2nd push or hear other thoughts on the topic of navigation with `Bloc` and `Equatable`.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround it is possible emit `MainInitial()` state right after `OpenSecondPageState()`.

I'm not consider this as final solution, but it more or less tidy.
Look for the `// <- Added part` in code.

updated bloc:

```dart
// main_bloc.dart
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

// bloc
class MainBloc extends Bloc<MainEvent, MainState> {
  MainBloc() : super(MainInitial()) {
    on<OpenSecondPageEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(OpeningSecondPageState());
      emit(MainInitial()); // <- Added part
    });                    
  }
}

// States
abstract class MainState extends Equatable {
  const MainState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class MainInitial extends MainState {}

class OpeningSecondPageState extends MainState {}

// Events
abstract class MainEvent extends Equatable {
  const MainEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class OpenSecondPageEvent extends MainEvent {}
```

UI part is the same